# Python List Coding Exercise - How do I repeat the same operation three times within a nested function?

Tags: python, list, append, repeat

I am working on a list exercise in Python where I am creating a function that appends the sum of the last two numbers in a list. Then I need to repeat the process two more times using the new list created by the first returned result.

I have the first part right and I can get the code to add the first value to the list. The problem is I can't figure out how to repeat the process two more times.

Here is what I have;

```
#This section adds the last two numbers together and appends to lst
  lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
  return lst

#I tried doing this but it produced the exact same result
  lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
  return lst
  lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
  return lst

#Uncomment the line below when your function is done
print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))

#After I run the code I get
[1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You are returning from the function after the first operation so the second and third operations never occur. Remove the first two `return` statements from your function

Comment: Try to think logically about the code. What does `lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])` do? How many times should that happen? What does `return lst` do? *How many times should* **that** *happen*?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you return the list after your first call, thus the second two calls don't happen.

Just replace your calls with a for loop as follows and you should be fine:

```
def list_sum(lst):
    for _ in range(3):
        lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
    return lst
    
print(list_sum([1,1,2]))
```

(this prints `[1,1,2,3,5,8]`)

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. I should only return once, there is no need to return in between lines. 

I could have done this in two ways. Either repeated the line three times and then returned the list or use the for loop to iterate three times with range(3).

I am learning but improving everyday. :-)